# Reduce gcloud Google Compute Platform CLI verbosity

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

Is there a way to make `gcloud` tool a bit less verbose?

There are the following global flags:

- `-q`
- `--verbosity [...]`
- `--no-user-output-enabled`

For many `create` commands, after the status of the command:

```
Created [resource URL]
```

a table is displayed also with the resource created.

```
Created [resource URL].
NAME    HOST  PORT  REQUEST_PATH
test-5        80    /
```

(in this example I was creating `http-health-checks` resources)

I would like to see only the status `Create ...`

`-q` and `--verbosity` have no effects. `--no-user-output-enabled` will hide the entire output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, gcloud commands print the result of a command to standard out, and all other information to standard error.

The result of the command varies from command to command, but in this case it is the table of resources that were created.  You can suppress this by redirecting stdout to /dev/null or you can use the `--format=none` to specify that you don't want the result printed.  You can see `gcloud topic formats` for more information on how formats work.

All other output is going to stderr (including the Created ... message).  The `--verbosity` flag controls logging verbosity (it is set to warning by default so you probably are not seeing any logging messages in the terminal).

`--no-user-output-enabled` will suppress both the status messages and the printed table.

`--quiet` suppress prompts, but does not generally control verbosity.